# Tension in a chain around a cone

Tags: forces

A chain of some mass, forming a circle, is slipped on a smooth cone.
If we consider an infinitesimally small section of the chain, a component of gravity will try to accelerate it along the surface of the cone. So there must be some tension in the string that prevents the acceleration. What will be the direction of the tension on this section of the chain?

Will it be towards the height of the cone, parallel to the ground?

Comment: Just for clarification: is the chain a ring perpendicular to the cone axis or do we have to analyze an arbitrary configuration of the chain around the cone?

Comment: @CuriousOne perpendicular to the cone axis(each element of the chain is at the same height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the angle of the cone is $\theta$, the radius of the ring is $r$ and the length density of the ring is $\rho$. Take a small segment of the ring that corresponding to an angle $\phi$, then the mass of this segment would be 
$$m=r\phi \rho$$
the normal force from the cone would be
$$N=\frac{mg}{\mathrm{sin}(\theta/2)}$$
If the tension on the ring is $T$, then we have 
$$2T\mathrm{sin}(\phi /2)=N\mathrm{cos}(\theta/2)$$
and consequently we have upon substituting in the expression for $N$
$$2T\mathrm{sin}(\phi /2)=r\phi \rho g \mathrm{cot}(\theta/2)$$
Now we take $\phi$ to be very small, which means $\mathrm{sin}(\phi /2) \approx \phi /2$, then we have 
$$T=r\rho   g \mathrm{cot}(\theta/2)$$
which only depends on the size and density of the ring and the angle of the cone, just as expected.

Comment: What about the direction?

Comment: the direction is tangent to the circle

Comment: I don't think the analysis is correct though. For example, the normal force from the cone is actually $mg / \sin{(\theta /2)}$. To see this, look at the ring as a whole: the z-component of normal force $N \sin \theta$ needs to balance the weight $mg$.
I think you obtained your normal force by resolving along the direction perpendicular to the cone surface. However, bare in mind that the tension as a whole results in radially-inward force on the ring as a whole. You used that in the later half of your calculation, but forgot to factor that at the start when you resolved perpendicular to cone

Comment: See my solution for two approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let the cone angle at the apex be $2\alpha$.

**Method 1 (Force considerations)**

Consider a small arc of the ring subtended by angle $d\phi$. The tension $T$ acts tangential to both ends of this arc. This results in a radially-inward force of $2T \sin{(d\phi /2)}$.

Now consider the entire ring. The forces acting on it are:

- $mg$ vertically downards
- normal force $N$ all around the ring acting perpendicular to cone surface
- radially inward force due to tension

Resolving along vertical direction yields $N = mg / \sin{\alpha}$. The normal force acting along a small arc of the ring subtended by angle $d\phi$ is  $\frac{d\phi}{2\pi} N$. Now resolving along the horizontal direction yields

$$\frac{d\phi}{2\pi} N \cos {\alpha} = 2T \sin{(d\phi /2)}$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{2\pi} mg \cot {\alpha} = 2T \sin{(d\phi /2)}$$

In the limit $d\phi \to 0$, $\sin{(d\phi /2)} \to d\phi /2$, so

$$ T = \frac{mg}{2\pi} \cot \alpha $$

**Method 2 (Work-energy)**

At equilibrium, the drop in gravitation potential energy by losing a height of $dh$ equals the work done by the tension $T$ in stretching the ring. (The normal force acts perpendicular to the direction of ring movement if the ring slides, so does no work).

A change of height $dh$ changes the ring radius by $dh \tan \alpha$, and thus changes the ring circumference by $2\pi (dh) \tan \alpha$. Therefore

$$T 2\pi (dh) \tan \alpha = mg(dh) $$

$$ T = \frac{mg}{2\pi} \cot \alpha $$

Comment: nice work, but it's the same thing

Comment: @M.Zeng I now realized that our $N$ are different because you made a typo in your solution (should divide by $\sin$ instead of multiply by $\sin$. You also forgot the $g$ in another typo. That's why I thought the solutions were different