# Tension in ring around a cone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

This question is an extension of the following question [Tension in a chain around a cone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134256/tension-in-a-chain-around-a-cone)

What I am not able to understand in the fbd is that why is the normal force acting outwards and not inwards like this [image]

Why is the figure (I) correct but not the second figure (II). I know that in equilibrium normal balances the weight, but as of what I've studied I've always seen normal acting perpendicular to the surface towards the object and not away from it. How can it act away from it? Especially if instead of chain (as in the figure) I put a rigid ring that doesn't "bend".

Comment: Are you asking about the normal force acting on the chain due to the cone??

Comment: The fbd of chain is drawn so yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the fbd of chain only, normal force must be acting outward on the chain due to the cone. As you have stated in your question itself, normal force acts towards the object perpendicular to the surface and this is possible for the chain only if the normal force acts outward from the cone (the direction from cone to chain is outward direction). If it is considered acting inwards, then the normal force will act away from the chain and towards the cone. This will be actually the normal force acting **on** the cone **due to** the chain instead which is equal in magnitude but opposite to the direction of the normal force acting **on** the chain **due to** the cone according to Newton's third law. In the fbd of a system, we consider external forces acting **on** the system, not the forces acting **due to** the system on some other object.

---

**Edit:**

Normal force always pushes an object, it never pulls on it. In this case, the normal force from the cone pushes the chain outward as shown in the figure below:-

[image]

I have given a magnified view of the point at which the chain and the cone meet in order to clearly illustrate that the normal force from the cone pushes the chain outward. The actual FBD seemed to give a wrong impression that the chain is being pulled outward by the normal force as the normal force seemed to originate from the chain itself but the magnified view makes it very clear that the normal force is being supplied by the cone and it pushes the chain outward.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But how can the normal force "pull" the ring since it clearly acts outwards in the scenario depicted

Comment: Should I just consider the fact that the ring is given in equilibrium and that is why normal should act in that way to balance the tension and weight components, I understand your explanation but it is just that in most scenarios I have seen normal being used when one object is placed over the other and so it acts and pushes the object against gravity but in that case, the objects in contact are one below the other so it seems more intuitive to understand

Comment: @protus I have edited my answer accordingly to clear the doubts raised in the comments above.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot the magnified view made it very clear. I was thinking that the ring lies "inside" the cone and that is why the confusion arose. Thanks +1